# Impute missing value error in rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer, data-cleaning

I have a sample data of some students in with **subjects**, **grades**, **semester** column values. In this data set I have some missing values in **semester** column, I need to impute those missing values by learning the existing values in **semester** column. For this I am using **Rapid Miner**, see the below image in which I am using 2 processes of retrieve data and impute that data, [image: Processes]

when I try to execute the flow it shows me below error:
[image: ERROR]

I tried to change the data type of **semester** column from numerical to real also but no success, there is no such kind of solution on the web too, can anyone have suggestions?

**UPDATED**
Below is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="8.1.001">
  <context>
   <input/>
   <output/>
   <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="8.1.001" expanded="true" name="Process">
  <process expanded="true">
  <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="8.1.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve" width="90" x="179" y="85">
  <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Local Repository/testing data 2"/>
  </operator>
  <operator activated="true" class="impute_missing_values" compatibility="8.1.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Impute Missing Values" width="90" x="380" y="85">
    <parameter key="attribute_filter_type" value="single"/>
    <parameter key="attribute" value="Semester"/>
    <parameter key="attributes" value="Subjects|Semester|Grades|GPA|Course Code|Batch"/>
    <process expanded="true">
      <connect from_port="example set source" to_port="model sink"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_example set source" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_model sink" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
  <connect from_op="Retrieve" from_port="output" to_op="Impute Missing Values" to_port="example set in"/>
  <connect from_op="Impute Missing Values" from_port="example set out" to_port="result 1"/>
  <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
  <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
  <description align="center" color="yellow" colored="false" height="105" resized="false" width="180" x="158" y="110">Type your comment</description>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

One more thing is when I run the process along with the above error I can see the resulted output by clicking the result output icon as below:

[image: Get output data]

I have total of 54 records in my file out of which 7 are missing values in **semester** column, and resulted output shows 47 records, it removes those missing values records, should these missing values be replaced with some other value??why it is removing those records??

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you try to connect a data set (called ExampleSet in Rapidminer) to another Operator that requires a model as input.
When you are unsure about the input and output of an Operator you can hover over the ports or press F1 (Show Operator Info in the right-click context menu) and you'll see more information.

In general it is also always very helpful to attach the process xml to a question, so others can directly copy and inspect your process (sans the data of course). The xml view can be found under *View -> Show Panel -> XML* in the menu bar.

Best

Answer (score 0):

The `Impute Missing Values` operator requires another operator inside it that takes an example set and produces a model. The idea is that all columns with missing values are iterated over as labels and the model predicts what the missing value would be. It basically assumes that the missing values are test data and the non missing is training data. There is an example process available - if you go to the help for the `Impute` operator and scroll to the end, you will find a process that loads some data with missing values and imputes these.

Comment: You still need a model inside the `Impute Missing Values` operator. At the risk of repeating myself, look at the help for this operator.